# Do WHERE ID IN with a subquery which returns a string of ID's

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make custom code for a Wordpress project. I need to get the product gallery.

This is the query to get all the ID's of the productimages of that product. This returns a string like for example "212, 213, 214".

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='_product_image_gallery' AND post_id=?
```

Then I use it as a subquery like this:

```
SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN (SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='_product_image_gallery' AND post_id=?)
```

The problem is that the `WHERE ID IN` is not working because the subquery returns a string of the ID's and does not view the ID's as separate instances. This is because all the productimages ID's are stored in a single cell.

How do I fix this? Is there some kind of `split()`  function?

**TL;DR**

I need to convert

```
SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN ("213, 214, 215")
```

to

```
SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN (213, 214, 215)
```

knowing that `"213, 214, 215"` is retrieved from a subquery.

**View of the row the subquery returns:**
[image: Wordpress row product gallery]

Comment: *This returns a string like for example "212, 213, 214".* Do you want to say that this is a value which is stored in one column of one row? You store a lot of values in CSV?

Comment: @Akina Yes, this is how Wordpress stores it. I'm not a fan of it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT guid 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(
  ID, 
  REPLACE((SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='_product_image_gallery' AND post_id=?), ' ', '')
)
```

I use `REPLACE()` because I see that there are spaces in the comma separated list.

Comment: This returns an empty result.

Comment: @O'Niel then maybe the id does not match any item of he comma separated list, or the list is not as you described it. Post sample data.

Comment: It works. My test-data was corrupted (altered it manually for this question). Thanks for the quick response mate.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. Do you have suggestions for how to achieve the same outcome without a where clause in the subquery?